# prepare mentions and hashtags to parse array object

Tags: arrays, regex, swift, parse-platform, hashtag

this is my first post and question. Here is what i'm doing to collect hashtags from UIText Field. It's working but I think this is not the correct way to do this. Any ideas? I need an array of hashtags as words.

Need to collect these type of tags: "Hey, this is my first photo!**#photo** **#hashtag** **#daily**:)

Here is my code;

```
 // Prepare words
    let words:[String] = titleTxt.text!.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
    self.taggyArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)


    // define tagged word if #
    for var word in words {


        if word.hasPrefix("#") {

            // cut symbold
            word = word.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.punctuationCharacterSet())
            word = word.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.symbolCharacterSet())

            // now prepare adjacent tags
            let tags:[String] = word.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.init(charactersInString: "#"))


            for tag in tags {
                taggyArray += [tag]

            }
        }

    }
```

And save to server

```
 object["hashtags"] = taggyArray
```

Is it possible to work this just with one regex seperation? Thank you,

Comment: I don't know anything about Swift, but I imagine the regex would be `(?<=#)\w+`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
  let matches = regex.matchesInString("(\#\w+)", ""Hey, this is my first photo!#photo #hashtag #daily:)")
  println(matches)
```